# "Dereferencing" data from a databound GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that is bound to a select statement from a table. That table contains a lot of keys out to other tables that are just IDs. I would like the GridView to "dereference", as it were, the id of the field in question and display the human-readable name found in the other table.

At the moment, the options that come to my mind are composing a DataSet by hand in the codebehind and binding the GridView to that instead of the SqlDataSource or creating a stored procedure to return the table already "dereferenced". Any other ideas or recommendations for this situation? I am using .NET 2.0 per employer mandate.

EDIT: Please see ["Dereferencing" data from a databound GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370038/dereferencing-data-from-a-databound-gridview) for the non-community-wiki version of this question. Please also reply to my comment below about community wiki. I get the feeling that the SO community is obsessed with rep and that is like lame.

Comment: You should re-ask the question without community wiki.

Comment: Why? Some dude told me that if there was a generic question that doesn't necessarily have a "right answer" I should use community wiki so that contributors don't feel butthurt when I don't accept an answer amid a group of equally-good answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Dereferencing" data from a databound GridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370038/dereferencing-data-from-a-databound-gridview)

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing to do would be to join to the other tables in your SELECT query and return the text fields directly from the database instead of the IDs.